# Plotting multiple repeated tasks

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, gantt-chart

I tried to plot multiple tasks in horizontal bars with Python.

I have timestamps on the x axis and tasks on the y axis. These tasks appear multiple times a day so I need to display many of them in one row. All together like a giant diagram with multiple tasks and gaps

Any idea how to plot this? It's enough to send me the name of the diagram. I searched but found nothing what I need. I need something similar like the attached picture

[image]

Comment: Is maybe a gantt chart suitable for you: https://plot.ly/python/gantt/ ?

Comment: thanks, thats what i was searching for